# How to replace mutableStateListOf values in one operation?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

I'd like to update an instance of `mutableStateListOf` in one operation so that the UI doesn't flicker between flushing old values and setting the new one. Is this possible? I looked at what autocomplete suggests, but I didn't find any *pause* & *resume* or similar APIs.

```
val dataset = mutableStateListOf<String>("foo", "bar")

dataset.clear() // <-- UI flickers to zero
dataset.add("bas") // <-- UI shows new numbers
```

The list holds names of datasets that need to be switched based on operations a user requests. Let's say there are `foo` & `bar` active now and the user decides to switch to `baz`. The switching makes the UI flicker because I cannot find a way of performing that switch in a single step.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the documentation  for [`SnapshotStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList#prependStateRecord(androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.StateRecord)) and found the `prependStateRecord` that does the trick:

```
dataset.prependStateRecord(mutableStateListOf("baz").firstStateRecord)
```

Comment: You should create an issuetracker request for a method to atomically replace the contents of SnapshotStateList, that kind of method is clearly missing.

Comment: Also, I wonder if using a plain List (without mutating it but replacing the entire object at once) or kotlinx ImmutabeList/PersistentList might work better for you.

Comment: I thought about replacing it with an ordinary list as in the long run there are just too many workarounds to make it work this way.